# Android - How to apply gradient color to bitmap?

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, gradient

I need to apply dynamically a gradient color to a bitmap (it looks like a scratch with some transparent parts) that will be draw over another bitmap: [this is the result i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6wAd.jpg).

This is my code:

```
Bitmap bitmapbackground = bitmaporiginal.copy(bitmaporiginal.getConfig(), true);

Bitmap bitmaptocolor = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.scratch);

LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, bitmaptocolor.getHeight(), Color.parseColor("#D81B60"), Color.parseColor("#F48FB1"), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setShader(gradient);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapbackground);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmaptocolor, 0, 0, paint);
```

But in this way it does not apply the gradient color to the scratch (it remains always black). What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `bitmaptocolor.getHeight()` is actually returning height.

Use hexadecimal equivalent for color.

```
LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, bitmaptocolor.getHeight(), 0xD81B60, 0xD81B60, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

Comment: I tried to set an explicit height and hexadecimal colors but the result does not change. However, if I draw a rectangle with canvas.drawRect(0, 0, x, y, paint), this is colored correctly. I really do not understand why it does not apply to drawBitmap.